# Switching between tabs in NERDTree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I've just started using the NERDTree vim plugin for my project.

I can't find the documentation for switching between opened tabs. Can anyone tell me the shortcut key[s] ?

Thanks...

Comment: Note: The tabs functionality is a standard feature of vim (since version 7) - though NERDTree happens to put them to good use

Comment: I use macvim, which can use cmd+number to switch between many tabs and it's very convenient! For example press cmd+1 jump to tab1, cmd+5 jump to tab5

Answer (score 234, accepted):

An additional option (and my personal choice)beyond the ones listed by Michael Madsen:

`gt` = next tab

`gT` = previous tab

Comment: where did you get this information - I do not see it in doc when using ? for info in the tree

Comment: It seems like nerdtree is only open within 1 tab, so by switching to the other,  the dir tree disappears.

Comment: if NewdTree tab is closed, use ":NERDTreeFocus" to reopen it.

Answer (score 41):

I like to bind my vim navigation keys to switching between tabs.  Here are the lines from my `.vimrc` file:

```
map  <C-l> :tabn<CR>
map  <C-h> :tabp<CR>
map  <C-n> :tabnew<CR>
```

That way, I can switch between tabs using the left and right buttons just like I normally would move the cursor, except I just hold the <kbd>Control</kbd> key as well.

- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> moves to the next tab
- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> moves to the previous tab
- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> creates a new tab

Comment: interesting. this will certainly com in handy. is it possible to change the mapping for VIM navigation commands like the difficult to hit SHIFT+$ ?

Comment: Are you referring to moving to the end of the line?  If so, a simple command can do this 'map <C-l> $' or something similar.

Answer (score 17):

A quick check in `:h tabs` reveals it's <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Page Down</kbd> to cycle between tabs. You can also use the `:tabnext` command (`:tabn` for short).

Comment: Neither `Ctrl` button works when vim is run in terminal an using terminal tabs. If not using terminal tabs then either `Ctrl` works

Answer (score 12):

I use iTerm on the mac, and I like being able to switch to the next/previous tabs using Shift-[left arrow key] and Shift-[right arrow key]

From my .vimrc, here's how to do the same thing in MacVim;

```
  map <S-Right> :tabn<CR>
  map <S-Left>  :tabp<CR>
```

FYI, by default, the key combos Cmd-Shift-[ and Cmd-Shift-] will switch between tabs in MacVim (and in Google Chrome, Safari and probably a bunch of other stuff)

Answer (score 10):

`Ctrl + ww` cycle though all windows

`Ctrl + wh` takes you left a window

`Ctrl + wj` takes you down a window

`Ctrl + wk` takes you up a window

`Ctrl + wl` takes you right a window

Comment: This really worked like a charm. I am using vim in Ubuntu18. Thank you for your knowledge contribution. Appreciate it

Answer (score 7):

my settings

```
map <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<cr>
map <C-Right> :tabn<cr>
map <C-Left> :tabp<cr>
```

Answer (score 7):

To enable Tab navigation like firefox add this to your vimrc:

```
nnoremap <C-S-tab> :tabprevious<CR>
nnoremap <C-tab>   :tabnext<CR>
nnoremap <C-t>     :tabnew<CR>
inoremap <C-S-tab> <Esc>:tabprevious<CR>i
inoremap <C-tab>   <Esc>:tabnext<CR>i
inoremap <C-t>     <Esc>:tabnew<CR>
inoremap <C-S-w>   <Esc>:tabclose<CR>
```

Also this come in handy Use `<A-Fn>` to go to the nth tabpage

```
nnoremap <A-F1> 1gt
nnoremap <A-F2> 2gt
nnoremap <A-F3> 3gt
nnoremap <A-F4> 4gt
nnoremap <A-F5> 5gt
nnoremap <A-F6> 6gt
nnoremap <A-F7> 7gt
nnoremap <A-F8> 8gt
nnoremap <A-F9> 9gt
nnoremap <A-F10> 10gt
```

Where,

```
  C --> ctrl key
  S --> Shift key
  A --> Alt key
  F1-10 --> Are the function keys
```

NOTE: Alt + f4 is usually used for closing of the windows. So check for that. If problem persists you can always map Ctrl or Shift key instead of Alt key, or use some combination of these.

Answer (score 7):

`'{TabNumber} + gt'` will allow you toggle to tab `{TabNumber}`.

For example, going to tab 1 will be keying '1' followed by 'g' and 't'.

The tab number is incremental from 1 left to right.

Comment: This answer is awesome!

Comment: is there a command to "toggle to last tab" or "toggle to first tab" ?

Answer (score 3):

Adding to digitalronin's answer, I think that the primary browser shortcut (at least in Chrome and Firefox) for switching tabs is option+command+right or left arrow.

If you want to keep your NERDTree Vim setup consistent with that, then this variation would work.

```
 map <D-A-Right> :tabn<CR>
 map <D-A-Left>  :tabp<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure vim to switch between tabs using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + arrow keys.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> arrow will switch to tab that is on the left of current tab.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> arrow will switch to tab that is on the right of current tab.

To achieve above behaviour update your vimrc with following lines:

```
nnoremap <C-Left> :tabprevious<CR>
nnoremap <C-Right> :tabnext<CR>
```

Reference: [Using vim tab pages](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Using_tab_pages)