# switching to different tab in vim

Tags: linux, vim

If I have opened 4 to 5 tabs in the same window.what is the shortcut to switch from tab1 to tab5/4.Pressing `gt` successively can get the work done. Is there any other easy way?

Comment: Are you using `gvim`?

Comment: @mbratch I m using both vi and gvim editor

Comment: Alternatively don't use tabs and learn to use [buffers effectively](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21338192/438329)

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/68509806/9384511

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a closer look at `:h gt`, it can be prepended with a `{count}`, so to go to tab5, you could hit <kbd>5gt</kbd> and to go to tab4 you could hit <kbd>4gt</kbd>.

Also, you can use <kbd>gT</kbd> to go to the previous tab (in the reverse direction), so from tab1 if you'd like to go to the last tab, it's faster to do <kbd>gT</kbd> than <kbd>{count}gt</kbd>

Comment: To facilitate using the count, it helps to put the tab number right in the tabline: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Show_tab_number_in_your_tab_line

Comment: @Ben that's right, and for terminal vim (what I use), you could use this https://gist.github.com/dhruvasagar/9995388