# Switching nodes (tabs) NerdTree vim on insertions mode

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, nerdtree

I've been searching for the shortcut to switch tab when i'm in insertion mode. I know by pressing `gT` or `gt` for switching tab on visual mode. Is nerdTree already have this features or do I need to map the key for this?

Comment: Don't switch tabs in insert mode, that's what normal mode is for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching between tabs in NERDTree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413005/switching-between-tabs-in-nerdtree)

Answer (score 0):

First, this has nothing to do with NERDTree. Tabs are a built-in feature of Vim. It may be more useful with NERDTree (as you open multiple locations in different tabs), though.

If you go to the `:help` page of `gt`, you'll see all alternative keys:

> ```
> :tabn[ext]                *:tabn* *:tabnext* *gt*
> <C-PageDown>              *CTRL-<PageDown>* *<C-PageDown>*
> gt                    *i_CTRL-<PageDown>* *i_<C-PageDown>*
> ```

In Vim's help, the `i_` prefix represents *insert mode*. So, the built-in mapping to switch tabs in insert mode is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PageUp</kbd> / <kbd>PageDown</kbd>.

If you want to use different keys, you can use mappings like the following:

```
inoremap <C-Tab>   <C-\><C-N>:tabnext<CR>
inoremap <C-S-Tab> <C-\><C-N>:tabprevious<CR>
```